# Float is ceiling-ed in some cases

Tags: ruby, floating-point

- `2.333333333333333333333` is rounded up to `2.3333333333333335`.
- `1.X3333333333333333` is sometimes rounded up to `1.X333333333333334`, but sometimes not.
- `0.X333333333333333` is not rounded up.

  ```
  1.33333333333333333333
  # => 1.3333333333333333
  1.43333333333333333333
  # => 1.4333333333333333
  1.53333333333333333333
  # => 1.5333333333333334
  1.63333333333333333333
  # => 1.6333333333333333
  1.73333333333333333333
  # => 1.7333333333333334
  1.83333333333333333333
  # => 1.8333333333333333
  1.93333333333333333333
  # => 1.9333333333333333
  ```

Is it a bug or just precision undefined behavior?

Comment: Looks like a floating point rounding error, not every number can be represented exactly

Comment: As always, http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: I think it's just standard floating point rounding error, you can [test it here and see it gives the same rounding error as your first example](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/Decimal.html).

Answer (score 1):

In IEEE 754 floating-point, numbers closer to zero are represented with smaller (better) absolute precision. Even without looking at the detail of [the “double-precision” binary representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), it is completely normal and to be expected that:

- an arbitrary number around `2.3333333333333333` can sometimes only be represented to within 0.0000000000000002,
- numbers between `1` and `2` can be represented about to within 0.0000000000000001, and
- numbers between `0` and `1` can be represented to a precision better than 0.0000000000000001.

---

If you do look at the detail of the representation, you will see that the precision changes every power of two (that is, it is the same for all numbers between 1 and 2 and it is the same for all numbers between 2 and 4, and the precision for numbers between 2 and 4 is worse than that for numbers between 1 and 2 by a factor of two).

For numbers between 1 and 2, the precision is 1/2<sup>52</sup>. That is in decimal `0.0000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625`. If you choose an arbitrary number between 1 and 2, **even one with a simple decimal representation**, you cannot expect that it will be represented more accurately than half this precision.

If you have some leeway in the numbers you choose to represent but want them to be represented exactly as double-precision IEEE 754 floating-point numbers, do not pick numbers that have a simple representation in decimal but numbers that have a simple representation in binary. These are for instance the numbers that are written in decimal `0.5`, `0.25`, `0.375`, …